# How to fetch field value of an object while using PROMISE

Tags: lightning-web-components

**Below code is for record creation.**

```js
createGuestRecord(){

const fields = {
    'Guest_First_Name__c': this.firstName,
    'Guest_Last_Name__c': this.lastName,
    'Guest_Phone__c': this.phone,
    'Guest_Email__c': this.email
};

const recordInput = {
    apiName: 'Guest_Master__c',
    fields
};

createRecord(recordInput).then(response => {

console.log('Guest record has been created',response.id);

console.log(response);
```

**console logs:**

[image]

//record id fetch is working but when I'm doing **response.Name** then value is coming as null (**Name** is a field in the returning object as highlighted in the picture.
Tried everything but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot, `Name` is not an attribute of `response`, but it's an attribute of `fields`. That's why `response.Name` is undefined.
If you want to get "GC-181" you should try `console.log(response.fields.Name.value);`

Comment: can't thank you enough. 
you saved my day. Thanks :)